# Fetching data from sqlite is very slow in blackberry

Tags: database, performance, blackberry, sqlite

I have 168mb sqlite database in sdcard containing nearly 30 tables each with more than 1000 records. i am using this query to fetch results from database.

```sql
select code mfr_code, name mfr_name
from manufacturers
where mfgr_type_code < 5 and code in (
        select mfgr_code
        from equipment_groups
        )
```

This query is taking more than 30 seconds in curve 5.0 and more than 1minute in torch 6.0 devices.

The subquery

```sql
SELECT mfgr_code FROM equipment_groups
```

is fetching more than 50k records.

same query when test in android is taking lessthan 5 seconds. What is the problem with blackberry.

Is there any way other way to reduce this processing time.

Edit

I am using this code to fetch results from database

```sql
     Vector vehical_type  = new vector()
Cursor cursor = statement.getCursor();
            while (cursor.next()) {
                Row row = cursor.getRow();
                vehical_type.addElement(row.getString(0));
            }
```

cursor.next() when executed for the first time is taking more than 10 for the query with IN.
and remaining 20 sec are taken by the loop to complete.

So i used the query with EXISTS as suggested below. Performance is improved a lot.

But what i observed is same cursor.next() is taking 1 sec for the first time and nearly 10 seconds to complete the loop.  So here i came to a conclusion that performance of loop is what effecting the total response time to fetch the entire data.

So is there any other approach to fetch the data other than looping the cursor.

Is there any possibility to improve the performance even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried rewriting your query? Here is a few idea:

If `equipment_groups.mfgr_code` column is not unique:

```
SELECT code mfr_code, name mfr_name
  FROM manufacturers
 WHERE mfgr_type_code < 5
   AND EXISTS (
           SELECT 1
             FROM equipment_groups
            WHERE mfgr_code = code
       );
```

If it is unique:

```
SELECT code mfr_code, name mfr_name
FROM      manufacturers
LEFT JOIN equipment_groups ON mfgr_code = code
WHERE mfgr_type_code < 5;
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. equipment_groups.mfgr_code column is not unique so i used first query but no luck it is taking more than 30 seconds in curve 5.0. When i execute those two queries individually i am able to get the results with in 10 seconds but when i combine them both it is taking lot of time. What could be the problem. Is it a device problem or in blackberry SQLITE performance is slow when dealing with huge data?

Comment: You could edit your question by adding every relevant `CREATE TABLE` statement to see what indexes do you have. You can also play with  `EXPLAIN`: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html Or you can read about the tricks of SQLite's optimizer: http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html